# Product Yield in Capability Analysis

Tags: data-transformation, quality-control

I couldn't find a 6 sigma tag so please let me know if this is posted in the wrong forum.

I'm performing a capability analysis on a manufacturing process. However my process output is Pass/Fail. This output would not let me use a normal distribution in my capacity analysis assumptions. If I calculate the % yield of the process, would my output allow me to use a good old fashioned capability analysis, assuming normality?

Comment: Capability analysis is not common terminology, could you explain what you are trying to do here? What are you testing?

Comment: Using observed data:
1. Define the data distribution for where the mean is centered and St.Dev.
2. Using defined spec limits, see what % of my observations will fall within my specifications.

It's not quite a question about capability analysis and more about the nature of the data.

Comment: I don't understand, is this a question about confidence intervals? Probabiliy of finding observations for a distribution in a given range?